# Can't add images to customized person model

Tags: azure-video-indexer

I currently have the problem that I can not upload images to person models using the Video indexer website anymore. Person models as well as the individual persons can be easily created and added.
But when I try to add images, no images are loaded.

The message "0 images uploaded" appears and does not change with time.I have already tried it with images that have already been successfully uploaded to other person models, but unfortunately it was also unsuccessful.

Does anyone perhaps have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for contacting us! I'm from Video Analyzer for Media team (former known as Video Indexer).
This is a bug that we are aware of and already been resolved.
It is currently in deployment to all regions, it will be available in the next 24hr.